# Acrobat library load doc Landscape

Tags: vba, pdf, acrobat

I want to have the file created in landscape, not sure what property (if there is one) to do this.
Default is always portrait.  I have the adobe libraries installed hence AcroAVDoc e.t.c.

```
Sub Test

Dim acApp As AcroApp, bavDoc As New AcroAVDoc, pdDoc As AcroPDDoc

bavDoc.Open strFile, ""

Set pdDoc = bavDoc.GetPDDoc

Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject

jso.SaveAs "c:\temp\doc.html"

jso.Open
          
End Sub
```

This create the pdf but in portrait.

Any ideas?  I did search google...